# preg_match issue: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: preg-match, delimiter

I know this issue has been discussed in different questions but the answers people have given don't seem to work on my end.  I'm dealing with the following problem:

```
if ( (preg_match($suspect, $lowmsg) )
  || (preg_match($suspect, strtolower($_POST['name'])))
  || (preg_match($suspect, strtolower($_POST['email']))))
```

Now, people have been saying that if I put `"/"` in front and behind quotes like so '/email/' that this would solve the problem.  I tried putting the / for email and name but it still brought me back to the same delimiter error.

I also get a final error of: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (my website's send.php:43) on line 61.  Does this have anything to do with it or is this just an error as a result of the earlier error?

Here's the entire code for interested parties:

```
<?php

 if(($_POST['email']=="")||($_POST['name']=="")||($_POST['message']==""))

 {

  echo "<html><body><p>The following fields are <strong>required</strong>.</p><ul>";

  if($_POST['name'] == ""){ echo "<li>Name</li>"; }

  if($_POST['email'] == ""){ echo "<li>Email</li>"; }

  if($_POST['message'] == ""){ echo "<li>Message</li>"; }

  echo "</ul><p>Please use your browser's back button to complete the form.</p></body></html>";

 }

 else

 {

  $message = "";

  $message .= "Name: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";

  $message .= "Email: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";

  $message .= "Message: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";

  $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject'], ENT_QUOTES);

  $pagelink = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pagelink'], ENT_QUOTES);

  $repemail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['repemail'], ENT_QUOTES);

  $injection_strings = array ( "content-type:","charset=","mime-version:","multipart/mixed","bcc:","cc:");

  foreach($injection_strings as $suspect)

  {

   if((preg_match($suspect, $lowmsg)) || (preg_match($suspect, strtolower($_POST['/name/']))) || (preg_match($suspect, strtolower($_POST['/email/']))))

   {

     die ( 'Illegal Input.  Go back and try again.  Your message has not been sent.' );

   }

  }

 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

 $headers .= "From: \"" . $_POST['/name/'] . "\" <" . $_POST['/email/'] . ">\r\n";

 $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST['/email/'] . "\r\n\r\n";

  mail($repemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

 header("Location: " . $pagelink . "");

 }

?>
```

Comment: Show your code. What is the content of $suspect?

Comment: could you print out suspect and physically show us what it contains please

Answer (score 0):

You can try other delimiters, such as / # ~

see [regexp.reference.delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Hope that helps.

EDIT: you do not need to do backslash inside $_POST

```
Use $_POST['name'] instead of $_POST['/name/']
```

EDIT: try

```
preg_match("/".$suspect."/i", strtolower($_POST['name']);
```

However, I dont think you would find any of your `$injection_strings` inside post name. You may need to rethink how you are searching. "content_type" is not going to match "text/html" with your current statement. You'd need to try other regex like

```
preg_match("/".$suspect."(.*)/i", strtolower($_POST['name'], $output);
```

So that it would `$output[0]`, your "suspect" variable. I'm not sure if thats what you are looking for, but maybe  sending you to the right track.

EDIT: Here.

If you want to look at say "cc:" and find what email it is, use this.

```
preg_match("/cc:(.*)/i",'cc:'.$_POST['email'],$output);
$output[0]; would equal your email.
```

To be compatible with your foreach loop, you may want to change it too,

switch this below code within your "if statements"

```
preg_match("/".$suspect."(.*)/i",$suspect.$_POST['email'])
```